# basic math equation math to java code

Tags: java, math

so i have a math equation that i need to use in java but for some reason my code is giving me small errors :(

the math equation is describe on [this web page](https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/2012/10/24/eve-sde-sql-blueprint-details/) in the section extra credit

my current code outpouts 4000 and the answere is 4005 what am i duing wrong ?

my test class lookes like this

```
        public class MainActivity {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                double baseMaterial =556;
                int me =5;
                int ml = 10;
                int extraMaterial = 3444;
                System.out.println(""+calculateMiniralTotal(baseMaterial,me,ml,extraMaterial));
            }
            public static double calculateMiniralTotal(double perfekt,int me,int ml,int extraMaterial) {
                double s = (perfekt + (perfekt * (10 / (ml + 1)) / 100));
                s = Math.round(s);
                double r = s + (perfekt * (0.25 - (0.05 * me)));
                r = Math.round(r);
                double q = extraMaterial + (extraMaterial * (0.25 - (0.05 * me)));
                q = Math.round(q);
                //double r=q;
                r = r + q;
                return Math.round(r);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your variable names are hard to understand, it makes the code unreadable.

Comment: the industry changes will frist become active in next releas witch is later this month. 
and i'm using fuzzworks material calculator to check for error witch runs on thies equations :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing integer division with `(10 / (ml + 1)) / 100`, which in Java must result in another `int`.  Your `ml` is `10`, and in Java, `10 / 11` is `0`, not `0.909`..., and nothing is added to `s`.

Use a `double` literal or cast to `double` to force floating-point computations.

```
double s = (perfekt + (perfekt * (10.0 / (ml + 1)) / 100));
```

or

```
double s = (perfekt + (perfekt * ( (double) 10 / (ml + 1)) / 100));
```

Making either change makes the output:

```
4005.0
```

Comment: omg i spend so many hours trying to track down that problem :( and the answer is that simple :(

tanks alot !!!

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply a double by an int you get an int back.

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        double baseMaterial = 556;
        int me = 5;
        int ml = 10;
        int extraMaterial = 3444;
        System.out.println("" + calculateMiniralTotal(baseMaterial, me, ml, extraMaterial));

    }

    public static double calculateMiniralTotal(double perfekt, int me, int ml, int extraMaterial)
    {
        double s = (perfekt + (perfekt * (10.0 / (ml + 1)) / 100.0)); // <-- changed from 10 to 10.0 and 100 to 100.0. This way they are doubles too
        s = Math.round(s);
        double r = s + (perfekt * (0.25 - (0.05 * me)));
        r = Math.round(r);
        double q = extraMaterial + (extraMaterial * (0.25 - (0.05 * me)));
        q = Math.round(q);
        //                          double r=q;

        r = r + q;
        return Math.round(r);
    }
}
```